# How can I use a Custom Channel of Action Cable with Stimulus Reflex and View Component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, stimulusjs, view-components, stimulus-reflex

So, I'm working on a project that should have a chat component same as the linkedin chat, where the user will have all their contacts and messages.

But, I've tried of all ways to work with `stimulus_reflex` and `view_component` to create this `chat_box`, but until now I had none progress.

So right now I'm trying to create a chat with pure action_cable, but my doubt is: Can I use this action_cable channel `('ChatRoom')` with `Stimulus Reflex`? Because when we see the rails console shows something like this: Broadcasting to `StimulusReflex::Channel:1`, and I want to Broadcast to the `ChatRoom Channel`.

Someone was tried the same?

Comment: I hope I could answer your question, but for StimulusReflex currently your best bet to get help is on the discord https://discord.com/invite/XveN625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stimulus_reflex` will use its own channel to update the page after a reflex. But those updates happen automatically and only for the user that triggered the reflex. Generally you don't want to touch those parts.

If you want to broadcast a message or a dom transformation after a reflex, you can do so by using `cable_ready` (which comes included with `stimulus_reflex`.

So something like this could work for you:

```rb
def my_reflex
  @chat = Chat.find(element.dataset[:chat_id])
  message = @chat.message.create(message: element.value)
  cable_ready["chatroom-#{@chat.id}"]. insert_adjacent_html(
    selector: "#chat",
    position: "beforeEnd",
    html: ApplicationController.render(ChatMessageComponent.new(message: message))                     
  )
end
```

For more possibilties you can check out the [cable_ready documentation](https://cableready.stimulusreflex.com/)

Comment: I've tried this way, but not worked for me. I decided to work with pure Action Cable to make my chat work as expected. I had some bad experience with reflex.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I have to write it as an answer. It looks like Roland was missing the actual broadcast of the cable_ready action.

```
def my_reflex
  @chat = Chat.find(element.dataset[:chat_id])
  message = @chat.message.create(message: element.value)
  cable_ready["chatroom-#{@chat.id}"]. insert_adjacent_html(
    selector: "#chat",
    position: "beforeEnd",
    html: 
   ApplicationController.render(ChatMessageComponent.new(message: message))                     
  )

  cable_ready.broadcast
end
```